# Git pull not does not work when providing branch name in the command (git version 1.7.1)

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I am not being able to understand this case. Why just `git pull origin develop` does not do the `fast-forward`. Why I need to run `git pull` to update the files.

It is a server copy. Local changes are never made. Developers update their work in the `develop` branch and then a `pull` is performed on the server with the help of hooks.

Here is the terminal commands and output.

```
[dev1st@ds3 rosplay]$ git branch -vv
* develop d555ff7 [origin/develop: ahead 2] add comment
[dev1st@ds3 rosplay]$ git pull origin develop
From http://115.112.117.254/php/rosplay
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
[dev1st@ds3 rosplay]$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 2 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
[dev1st@ds3 rosplay]$ git pull
From http://115.112.117.254/php/rosplay
   2d3bb3a..d555ff7  develop    -> origin/develop
Already up-to-date.
[dev1st@ds3 rosplay]$ git status
# On branch develop
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I've set the tracking information correctly. But still for this project only, `git pull origin develop` won't do the `fast-forward`.

Please help.

### Update (`.git/config` content)

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = http://username:password@...php/rosplay.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "develop"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/develop
```

Comment: Post your `.git/config` related to the project and your own global `.gitconfig` if you have. Please omit sensitive information.

Comment: @PedroNascimento added the requested file content in question.

Comment: @PedroNascimento My Git version is `git version 1.7.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an older version of git (pre-1.8.4).

Remember first that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`,<sup>1</sup> but `git pull` passes additional arguments to these two steps.

When you run `git pull` with *no* additional arguments, `git pull` runs `git fetch origin`.<sup>2</sup>  If you add `origin develop`, however, `git pull` runs `git fetch origin develop`.  This last additional argument is a *refspec*.  With `git fetch`, a refspec that is missing a colon `:` character tells the fetch process to tell the other end (another git process, on the server) to ship over everything it has for the name, but then—in older versions of git only—to *skip* updating the `origin/name` version of that reference.  (The newly-brought-over items, if any, are deposited in the special reference `FETCH_HEAD` which you see in the output from the `git fetch` that `git pull` runs.)

What this means is that *this particular form of fetch*, and **only** this particular form, *skips* updating your `origin/develop`.

Once the fetch finishes, both forms of `git pull` do the merge (or rebase) as usual; in this case there is nothing to do, both times.

When you make `git pull` run `git fetch` such that your `origin/develop` is *not* updated, your git promptly forgets that `origin/develop` could have been updated.  You run `git status` and you see yourself as being "two commits ahead".

When you run `git pull` such that `git fetch` *does* update your `origin/develop`—note that `origin/develop` appears in the output, instead of `FETCH_HEAD`—your git now remembers the new `develop` it obtained from `origin`.  This time, `git status` shows you and `origin` being in sync.  This is because this time, you permitted your git to update its knowledge of the server's references (any fetched `origin/*` branches).

This particular weird behavior was eventually discarded (in git version 1.8.4), and if you update your own git, `git fetch origin develop` will update its idea of `origin/develop` and this strangeness will stop.  But it happens now because the four-argument `git fetch` form uses a no-colon refspec.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or followed by `git rebase` if so configured.  For this case it does not matter.

<sup>2</sup>In this case, anyway; the additional argument can name some repository other than `origin`.

Comment: plus one. Thanks your the detailed explanation. I will update the Git then.